# Div Background Change OnClick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have looked at this so long that I'm confusing myself. I seem to be stuck and missing something. My code is basically supposed to have the default div background (gamebg), and when you click on one of the buttons, the background of the div they are in changes.

```
<style>        
    #gamebg {
        background-color: #00b5d3;
        background-image: url('background_button_1.png');
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 950px;
        height: 800px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 20px;
    }

    .gamebg1 {
        background-color: #00b5d3;
        background-image: url('background_button_1.png');
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 950px;
        height: 800px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 20px;
    }

    .gamebg2 {
        background-color: #00b5d3;
        background-image: url('background_button_2.png');
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 950px;
        height: 800px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 20px;
    }

</style>

<div id="gamebg">

    <a href="#none" onclick="document.getElementById('gamebg').className ='gamebg1'"><img src="background_button_1.png" class="panel-button"></a>
    <a href="#none" onclick="document.getElementById('gamebg').className ='gamebg2'"><img src="background_button_2.png" class="panel-button"></a>

</div>
```

Any suggestions for me?

Comment: Change css to #gamebg.gamebg1 etc

Comment: Ha! This fixed it. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDs have a higher specificity than classes. In your case, `#gamebg` is overriding `.gamebg1`

It's also best not to put too much code in in-line JavaScript. Considering creating a function. Inside the function, you will use the `attribute` function to add a class, and the `removeAttribute` function to remove the id.

Now in `onclick`, you just need to call the function with the class you want to add inside the paramater.

Here is a solution for you

JavaScript

```
function addNewClass(className) {
    var background = document.getElementById('gamebg');
    background.attribute('class', className);
    background.removeAttribute('gamebg');
}

<a href="#none" onclick="addNewClass('gamebg1');"><img src="background_button_1.png" class="panel-button"></a>
<a href="#none" onclick="addNewClass('gamebg2')"><img src="background_button_2.png" class="panel-button"></a>
```

Here is more information on specificity

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: It's almost humiliating that I didn't pick that out. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

This is due to something called "specificity". In CSS, id's are more "specific" than a class, which is why the id's background-color property will always override the class' background-property, meaning the background-color property won't actually change while the classes bound to the node with that id will.

A good video about specificity here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fy07HYm-geM